# TemplateBinding in EventTrigger

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, custom-controls

I have the following Binding in an EventTrigger:

```
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="PreviewMouseDown">
        <SoundPlayerAction Source="{Binding Path=SoundFile, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Converter={StaticResource soundFileConverter}}" />
    </EventTrigger>
    ...
```

The process is the following: The custom control (that's its template) has a property named **SoundFile**, an enum type. In the converter this enum value should be converted to an Uri to pass it to the SoundPlayerAction.

Here's the problem: The converter isn't called anyway. The output window presents the following error:

> Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement for target element.
>       BindingExpression:Path=SoundFile; DataItem=null; target element is 'SoundPlayerAction'
>       HashCode=46763000); target property is 'Source' (type 'Uri')

What's wrong with the binding expression?

**EDIT:**

For a better overview, here's the entire template of the control:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type controls:Button}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type controls:Button}">
                <Border Name="Border"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="Transparent"
                        BorderThickness="0">
                    <Border.CornerRadius>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource areaCornerRadiusConverter}">
                            <MultiBinding.Bindings>
                                <Binding Path="RoundType" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}" />
                                <Binding Path="ActualHeight" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}" />
                            </MultiBinding.Bindings>
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </Border.CornerRadius>
                    <TextBlock Margin="{Binding Path=RoundType,
                                                RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},
                                                Converter={StaticResource buttonMarginConverter}}"
                               FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}"
                               Style="{StaticResource innerTextBlock}"
                               Text="{TemplateBinding Text}" />
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="PreviewMouseDown">
                        <SoundPlayerAction Source="{Binding Path=SoundFile, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Converter={StaticResource soundFileConverter}}" />
                    </EventTrigger>                        
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

**EDIT 2:**

I tried it in another way: Setting the name attribute of the SoundPlayerAction to **PART_SoundPlayerAction** and retrieving it from the code-behind with **GetTemplateChild**. But **GetTemplateChild** returns always null. That's really annoying. Nothing seems to work...

**EDIT 3:**

Now with the answer of Blachshma I got it that the converter is called during the initalization of the control. But not when the property is changing. Furthermore, the value which is returned by the converter, isn't applied as Source to the SoundPlayerAction.

I implemented the BindingProxy:

```
public class BindingProxy : Freezable
{
    #region Overrides of Freezable

    protected override Freezable CreateInstanceCore()
    {
        return new BindingProxy();
    }

    #endregion

    public SoundFile Data
    {
        get { return (SoundFile)GetValue(DataProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DataProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Data.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DataProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Data", typeof(SoundFile), typeof(BindingProxy), new UIPropertyMetadata(SoundFile.None));
}
```

And I changed the `Path=Data.SoundFile` to `Path=Data`. Is there any mistake?

**EDIT 4:**

The solution with the MakeSoundCommand is working perfectly. Thanks a lot to Blachshma.

Comment: SoundPlayerAction is a built-in wpf class, look at msdn: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.soundplayeraction.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you're right, trying to use binding in that specific place (An EventTrigger inside a style) is quite a pain.

I've found that the best way to solve this issue is to use both [Freezables](http://drwpf.com/blog/2008/05/22/leveraging-freezables-to-provide-an-inheritance-context-for-bindings/) (to inherit the DataContext) together with static BindingProxies...

To solve it in your case, start by making a freezable class, we'll call it BindingProxy:

```
public class BindingProxy : Freezable
{
    #region Overrides of Freezable

    protected override Freezable CreateInstanceCore()
    {
        return new BindingProxy();
    }

    #endregion

    public object Data
    {
        get { return (object)GetValue(DataProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DataProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Data.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DataProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Data", typeof(object), typeof(BindingProxy), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));
}
```

So our BindingProxy class implements `Freezable` and exposes a property named `Data`. This will be the Property which will hold the DataContext.

Now, in our resources, we'll create a StaticResource that uses this class... We'll name it "***proxy***":

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:BindingProxy x:Key="proxy" Data="{Binding}" />
```

Notice, that we bind the Window's DataContext into the `Data` property. This will allow use to access it from the `SoundPlayerAction`.

Finally, let's update the SoundPlayerAction to work with our proxy:

```
<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="PreviewMouseDown">
    <SoundPlayerAction Source="{Binding Source={StaticResource proxy}, Path=Data.SoundFile,Converter={StaticResource soundFileConverter}}" />
</EventTrigger>
```

Instead of the regular binding you used, we're binding to a StaticResource, the instance of our BindingProxy class. Since the `Data` property is binded to the DataContext of the window, we can get the SoundFile property using `Data.SoundFile`.
And as an added bonus, since all this is done via `Source={Binding` you can stil call your soundFileConverter to convert the string to a URI.

**Update:**
OP does not want to put the `BindingProxy` class inside some `<Window.Resources>` tag every time he uses this control (which is legitimate), so in this version, we're going to put all the logic inside the ResourceDictionary and modify a bit of XAML so that it continues to work..

So in our resource dictionary, we're going to use `System.Windows.Interactivity` and `Microsoft.Expression.Interactions` (both freely available through the [Blend SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10801))

```
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"
```

Since in the previous version we could count on the binding being preformed through the Window.Resources, this time we're going to have to do it ourselves... We'll modify the original template to add an `<i:Interaction.Triggers>` which will replace the `EventTrigger` but allows sounds to play through a dedicated command:

```
<local:MakeSoundCommand x:Key="soundCommand"/>
<Style  TargetType="{x:Type controls:Button}" >
  ....
  ....
   <i:Interaction.Triggers>
     <i:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewMouseDown">
        <local:EventToCommand Command="{StaticResource soundCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=SoundFile, Converter={StaticResource soundFileConverter}}" />
     </i:EventTrigger>
   </i:Interaction.Triggers>
   <TextBlock Margin="{Binding Path=RoundType,....
```

This is placed right before the TextBlock, what it does is handle the `PreviewMouseDown` event and calls the a command named `soundCommand` of type `MakeSoundCommand`.

This is the implementation of **MakeSoundCommand**:

```
public class MakeSoundCommand : ICommand
{
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        Uri uri = parameter as Uri;

        if (uri != null)
        {
            StreamResourceInfo sri = Application.GetResourceStream(uri);
            SoundPlayer simpleSound = new SoundPlayer(sri.Stream);
            simpleSound.Play();
        }
    }
```

The rest of the code remains the same.
Note: The `EventToCommand` used is the one from the [MVVM Light Toolkit](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/) and can be downloaded [here](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/b922e8ccf674#GalaSoft.MvvmLight/GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras%20%28NET4%29/Command/EventToCommandVS10.cs)

***Final Result:***

Generic.xaml:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
                xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"
                xmlns:local="<YOUR NAMESPACE>">

<local:MakeSoundCommand x:Key="soundCommand" />
<local:SoundFileToUriConverter:Key="soundFileConverter" />
<Style TargetType="{x:Type controls:Button}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType=" {x:Type controls:Button}">
                <Border Name="Border"
                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                    BorderBrush="Transparent"
                    BorderThickness="0">
                    <Border.CornerRadius>
                      ....
                    </Border.CornerRadius>
                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewMouseDown">
                          <local:EventToCommand Command="{StaticResource soundCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=SoundFile, Converter={StaticResource soundFileConverter}}" />
                        </i:EventTrigger>
                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <TextBlock Margin="{Binding Path=RoundType,
                                            RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" .... />
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: It always has to be more complicated doesn't it :)  I updated the answer to allow all this code to be in a ResourceDictionary

Comment: thx again. Now I've troubles using the Blend SDK libraries. I installed the Blend SDK but I can't find the dlls System.Windows.Interactivity and System.Window.Interactions, so therefore I can't add them as reference.

Comment: `c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Expression\Blend\.NETFramework\v4.0\Libraries` and notice I mistyped the second dll, its `Microsoft.Expression.Interactions`

Comment: ok, now the library itself is building, but the project where I included my library crashes at start with the following exception: **{"Could not load file or assembly 'System.Windows.Interactivity, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden.":"System.Windows.Interactivity, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"}**

Offtopic: How can I format the comment as you did so that some text is placed in gray boxes?

Comment: @oneoftwo - Try copying all the dlls from the SDK library to the directory in which you run the project. Did this help?

Comment: Have a look at Edit 3 of the question.

Comment: @oneoftwo [Click Here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21572/discussion-between-blachshma-and-one-of-two) to continue the discussion in chat.